# Insert key value pairs from array into SQL query string

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js

I have this code with array:

```
const dataToset = [
    { key: 'key1', value: "some data" },
    { key: 'key2', value: 37 },
];

await db.query(`
    UPDATE some_table 
    SET ${dataToset.map(data => `${data.key} = ${data.value}`)}
    WHERE id ${id}`);
```

result query is next: `UPDATE some_table SET key1=some data,key2=37 WHERE id=1`
and it fails, because `some data` should be passed as string.
How to get valid query: `UPDATE some_table SET key1="some data",key2=37 WHERE id=1`?

p.s. I am getting next error: syntax error near "data"

Comment: Isn't it `WHERE id=1`?

Comment: nope, fixed it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from syntax error (it has to be `WHERE id=1`), I would do explicit array to string conversion, using `.join(', ')` and somewhat change your template string, paying attention that (only) string value should be enclosed into **single** quotes:

```js
const dataToset = [
          { key: 'key1', value: "some data" },
          { key: 'key2', value: 37 },
      ],
      id = 1
      query = `
        UPDATE some_table
        SET ${
          dataToset
            .map(({key,value}) => 
              typeof value == 'string' ? 
              key+"='"+value+"'" : 
              key+'='+value)
            .join(', ')
        }
        WHERE id=${id}
      `

console.log(query)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;}
```